# DetailText loading in incorrect space in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Its hard to explain to images will help. When the UITableView first loads, the detailText is above the textLabel - as such:

[image]

But when you move the tableView around a bit, it corrects itself, as such:

[image]

Here is my code for adjusting for everything I feel is applicable:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }


    if (indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Two";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.rules objectForKey:@"two"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Three";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Four";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 3){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Five";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 4){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Six";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 5){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Seven";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 6){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Eight";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 7){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Nine";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 8){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Ten";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 9){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Jack";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 10){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Queen";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 11){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"King";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 12){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Ace";
    }
    CGRect frame = tableView.frame;

    UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-70, 10, 50, 30)];
    [addButton setTitle:@"Get" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 addButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:14.0f];
    addButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addButton];

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        [cell.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

The row height:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str = [self.rules objectForKey:@"two"];
    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return size.height + 40;
}
```

Comment: cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0; do this in if statement of cellForEowAtIndexPath after you initialise a cell

Comment: Not solved it unfortunately